# he has got a supply

Tags: grammar

My friend talked to his friend about his result. His friend said that you have failed in anatomy subject. After ending up a call he said to me "I got a supply in anatomy".
Using past simple with the action that has still linked with present, Is it fine?
I think he should have said . I have got a supply.because I got a supply means in past.
Supply means someone failed in a subject.

Answer (score 1):

The past tense is more appropriate in this context, because the failure is definitive and complete.

By contrast, the present perfect might be used if two students were leaving an exam, without, of course, knowing the results. One might say to the other ‘I know I’ve got a supply in anatomy’, to which the other might reply ‘Don’t be so pessimistic. You may have done better than you think.’ In that case, the first student’s use of the present perfect is appropriate, because the assumed result is relevant to the conversation.

Answer (score 0):

"I got a supply in anatomy" is correct when referring to the actual achievement. Similarly:

> I got an A in mathematics.
>
> I got the blue ribbon.

"Got" in this usage is equivalent to "received":

> I received an A in mathematics.
>
> I received the blue ribbon.
>
> I received a supply in anatomy.

If your friend was referring to a *current standing* of the grade then it should be "have got" or, more simply, "have":

> I have a supply in anatomy.
>
> I have an A in mathematics.
>
> I have the blue ribbon.